# Why is dataContext.GetChangeSet().Deletes.Count() always returning 0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I've got this going on:

```
var customerIdsToDelete = new {1, 2, 3};
var dataContext = new DataContext();
var customersToDelete = (from c in data.Customers
                         where  customerIdsToDelete.Contains(c.CustomerID)
                         select c);
data.Customers.DeleteAllOnSubmit(customersToDelete);
data.SubmitChanges();

var deletedCount = data.GetChangeSet().Deletes.Count();
```

Even when customers are successfully deleted `deletedCount` will be 0.

Why? And what would be the "correct" way of counting the number of `customers` deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you've submitted the changes already. Once the call to `SubmitChanges` has been made then there are no deletes, and therefore (correctly) a count of zero is returned. To get the number of items deleted (or, to be deleted) then try this (i.e. determining the count prior to pushing the changes):

```
...

var deletedCount = data.GetChangeSet().Deletes.Count();
data.SubmitChanges();

...
```

Comment: hrm, if for some reason a customer in the change set is NOT deleted (maybe there is some DB constraint preventing this) is there anyway to determine that?

Comment: Yes, your application would encounter an exception, assuming this would happen under exceptional circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Does your SubmitChanges method provide an override that takes a callback?

I've worked a bit with Silverlight and RIA Services, and the DomainContext's SubmitChanges method has an override of the form `SubmitChanges(Action<SubmitOperation>, object userState)`

We call it as follows:

```
mycontext.SubmitChanges( submitOperation => 
{
     //here, inside the callback, you can inspect
     //the submitOperation for the results
     //of the SubmitChanges method
}, null);
```