# Entity GetChangeSet() returns empty even there is an update

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

In linq-to-sql, when I try to get the changes from Entity.GetChangeSet() method, it returns [Inserts: 0, Deletes:0, Updates:0] even there is an update.

I'm using it as suggested before the commitChanges() call.
the problem occurs like this:

```
var item = Entity.GetItemById(itemId).FirstOrDefault();
item.Property1 = "Something";

var changes = Entity.GetChangeSet().ToList();
Entity.SubmitChanges();

//changes is: [Inserts: 0, Deletes:0, Updates:0]
```

Comment: After setting the item.Property1 to Something, Do you need to update to get it reflected. I am not sure, I have not tried..

Comment: as it is shown in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx), it is done before the submit changes like I mentioned in the question.

Comment: and it is declared [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011123/why-is-datacontext-getchangeset-deletes-count-always-returning-0) too

Comment: Are you sure that item.Property1 is not already set to "Something" and that your table has a primary key defined?

Comment: Yep, for both. I've checked a thousand times the before and after values of the property and it is a foreign key property.

Comment: Whether something is/has a Foreign key or not doesn't matter, but Linq2Sql does not track changes on a table if that table does not have a primary key defined.

Comment: I'm assuming Entity is actually a datacontext? I'm wondering about the capital letter. If Entity happens to be a property that was returning a new datacontext every time it was accessed, then this would explain things.

Comment: Entity is a dataContext and it is only initialized when the page loads in the page_load event and with a not postback condition. So when the form's submit is clicked, it is not initialized again.

Comment: I've found out that, in the entity designer; for Property1 property, through the properties of it, if I change the "Update Check" value from "Always" to "When Changed"; it gets the modified members. But I don't know how to set it to all of the properties of all the entities. help is appreciated.

Comment: @sgmoore The thing I'm talking about is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.updatecheck.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few bad days, I figured out that after deleting and recreating the entity, cleaning the solution helped me and the method worked like a charm.

I guess there was an update error that prevented it.